# Flash memory multiple device I/O operations

Tags: driver, flash

Can two devices perform I/O operations on flash memory simultaneously? For example if two USB hubs are connected to it and both are connected to two different laptops, can a flash memory have multiple access at all? If not, is there any way to approach this operation through a network or anything?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is how to control what gets done to the memory. For example, let's say both computers tried to overwrite the same file with differing contents - what should the result be? And they both will inevitably try it - if not any one file, then certainly the filesystem data.

If you want to access the same storage device from more than one computer, you can share it over the network (using nfs,smb,ftp or something else that shares *files*). Then the file server would be responsible for modifying the filesystem data and also for allowing or not allowing access to files (it may not allow write access to a file if it is open on another computer).

There is dual port RAM available (and it would probably be possible to make a dual port flash), but it is used when one port is used exclusively for reading, whiel the other could be used for reading or writing. And example would be the frame buffer of a video card - the processor reads/writes the memory while the DAC just reads it, converts to analog, and drives the VGA output).

Comment: doesn't the software (the filesystem) handle the I/O operations. I really do not mind writing my own filesystem that will have a lock system for simultaneous writing. I wanted to know if its physically possible to connect the flash memory into two hubs. I am going to check out the dual port RAM. can a dpram change the state for the devices?

Comment: Standard block device filesystem (FAT, NTFS, ext2...) drivers assume that the computer has exclusive access to the device (because almost always it is so).

And no, you cannot just connect the USB flash stick to two hubs. You would need a device that acts as a "reverse hub" and presents itself as the flash stick for both computers then somehow adds all commands and sends them to the stick. Either that device or your computers would have to decide which write commands should be executed and their order.

Comment: thanks for the information. It really game me a good direction on this situation.